# Drop empty childrens using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodes, removechild

I try to drop empty nodes using JavaScript, because the navigator count the return line or space like a child node

So, I make this try, first it's work correctly but if I count the nodes for the second time it's give me a number ( contains the empty nodes ) despite I make removechild

My code :

```js
  function testing(){
      var c = document.body.childNodes;
      for(i=0;i<c.length;i++){
        if(c[i].nodeName == "#text")
        {
          var rest = c[i].textContent;
          if(rest.length == 0){
            //I want to remove the empty nodes
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.childNodes[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      
      //this give a number contains the empty nodes
      var d =document.body.childNodes.length;
      alert(d);


    }
```

My HTML code

```html
<body onclick="testing()">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test1</p>
  </body>
```

If I try to know the length of this HTML code, the navigator give me **5** not **2** (it's count the return line and space)

So, for that I want to delete the empty nodes the take result **2**

Comment: maybe you have other children then empty text elements? how does your html look?

Comment: @Dr.Fre I add my HTML code

Comment: so your html contains `text` elements which you did not add to your example

Comment: @Dr.Fre I need first to detect if it a text or not, if it a text detect if had a text or empty, if it's empty, I need to delete it

Comment: if only the newline and spaces are a problem you can change the line `if(rest.length == 0){` to `if(/^[\s\n]{0,}$/.test(rest)){` as described in my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(c[i].nodeName == "#text")
```

At this line you check if it is a `#text` node but in your html are `p` elements.

```
var rest = c[i].textContent;
if(rest.length == 0){
    //I want to remove the empty nodes
    document.body.removeChild(document.body.childNodes[i]);
}
```

Also with those lines you check if the content of the element is empty which is also not the case in both of your `p` elements.

So your alert should correctly contain `2`.

---

If your problem is that you have `text` elements which contain whitespaces and newlines in your `body` element you can check for them with `regex`.

Just change this line

```
if(rest.length == 0){
```

To

```
if(/^[\s\n]{0,}$/.test(rest)){
```

---

And for the compleatness sake:

change the following line

```
for(i=0;i<c.length;i++){
```

To

```
for(i=len -1;i>=0;i--){
```

As described in @Bindrid's answer because you can miss `elements`.

---

So the compleate code should be

```js
function testing(){
  var c = document.body.childNodes;
  for(var i = c.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(c[i].nodeName == "#text") {
      var rest = c[i].textContent;
      if(/^[\s\n]{0,}$/.test(rest)) {
        //I want to remove the empty nodes
        document.body.removeChild(document.body.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }
  }
      
  //this give a number contains the empty nodes
  var d =document.body.childNodes.length;
  alert(d);
}
```

Comment: I use the regular expression, it's give the correct result, thanks a lot

Comment: @Saad always a pleasure to help

Comment: @Saad take a look at the post of `Bindrid` because he as detected an other problem in the code

Comment: @Saad you can copy the sippet I have added at the end. if you like it please leave an upvote

Answer (score 0):

An element is considered `empty` when has no content, *whitespaces, line return* are considered as content. So, you have two way depending on what you need. if you need for true empties elements use `document.querySelectorAll(':empty')`, otherwise, use `document.body.childNodes` and check if its content is empty with `String.prototype.trim`.
Hope it helps.

```html
<div>
  
</div>


<section></section>
```

```js
function isTextNode(element) {
  return element.nodeType === 3;
}

function removeEmptyTextNodes(element) {
  if(!isTextNode(element)) { return; }
  
  var content = (element.textContent || "").trim();
  if(content.length > 0) { return; }
  
  console.log("removing", element);
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}


Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.body.childNodes, removeEmptyTextNodes
);
```

```html
<div>
  
</div>

<span></span>
```

Comment: thanks, but why my code is not working ? if a make an alert in for it's give me the true result, but when I make it after for it's give me the false result

Comment: in your example `rest.length` represents the length of the string returned by `Node.prototype.textContent`, while `document.body.childNodes.length` represents the length of the `NodeList`, the number of items contained.

Comment: but I removed the `childNode` using this method `removeChild`

Comment: you remove only `textNodes` that have `no-content`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're overthinking it. You've observed the difference between childNodes and children, which is that childNodes contains all nodes, including text nodes consisting entirely of whitespace, while children is a collection of just the child nodes that are elements. That's really all there is to it.

```js
 function testing(){
      alert(document.body.children.length);
      var c = document.body.children;
      for(i=0;i<c.length;i++){
        if(c[i].innerHTML == "")
        {
            //I want to remove the empty nodes
            document.body.removeChild(c[i]);
        }
      }
      
      //this give a number contains the empty nodes
      var d =document.body.children.length;
      alert(d);


    }
```

```html
<body onclick="testing()">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test1</p>
    <p></p>
  ss
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(i=0;i<c.length;i++){
    if(c[i].nodeName == "#text")
    {
      var rest = c[i].textContent;
      if(rest.length == 0){
        //I want to remove the empty nodes
        document.body.removeChild(document.body.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

should actually be as shown below to take in account that you are removing nodes as you run through the list.  If node 7 and 8 are empty and you remove 7, 8 becomes 7 while you are in the 7 loop so 8 as the new 7 gets missed on the next loop.

```
var len = c.length;
for(i=len -1;i>=0;i--){
    if(c[i].nodeName == "#text")
    {
      var rest = c[i].textContent;
      if(rest.length == 0){
        //I want to remove the empty nodes
        document.body.removeChild(document.body.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```